# Minecraft Server not working

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, hosting, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I have recently bought the newest Minecraft.  That would be Minecraft Windows 10 Edition.

Like it and have been attempting to setup a Server.

These are the steps I took in an stab to get this up and in good working order.

Went out to the Minecraft [here](https://minecraft.net/en-us/).

Following that buried down to the downloads and got minecraft_server 1.11.2.jar

Unpacked this in a folder I made called "Minecraft" on my Windows 10 Pro desktop.

Updated the ELUA reran the java file and generated all the other needed folders.

At this point I can see that the server is up and running.

stop the server updated the IP in the Servers document that I am opening with Text editor to match my machine IP.

Then pulled up my router added the needed port of 25565 and computer IP for both internal and external connections in the port forwarding.

Turned back on the server at this point and tested that I am broadcasting with http://www.canyouseeme.org/ Everything checked out.

Lastly went out to my Windows Firewall and turned on the function to have Java TM Platform SE Binary is allowed on both Public and Private.

When I attempt to connect to the server in game it never detects.

Where is the issue at or do I have the wrong version and how do I get the new server install to make my own so I do not have to pay to play?

Thank you,

Comment: The server.jar only works for Java Minecraft not W10 edition. Try buying a realm.

Comment: Ah, well that means this is getting returned.

Comment: There are MCPE server makers that work with Windows 10 Edition.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is not a server version for Windows 10 edition. You are using the server for the Java version of Minecraft.
You can either use that server in Minecraft Java or wait until a Windows 10 edition server is published if it even is going to be.
Also buying a Realm is an option: https://minecraft.net/en-us/realms/

Comment: Thanks Jusola for the response, After doing some research it looks like I maybe able to use the Minecraft PE server version to get this in working order,since I can connect to Liveboat.  Thus far have it running only as Lan.  When I attempt a connection all it tells me is it cannot connect to the World.  Worst case I return this and get the java version of Minecraft..

Answer (score -2):

Do you have the 32bit or 64bit version of Java matching your OS?  They both need to be the same bits to work properly.

Comment: That's not true at all. Java 32 can run on a 64-bit computer. Do some research before posting.